# Pass ref to default slot in renderless component

Tags: vue.js, renderless-component

I am trying to build a renderless component in vue 3 and want to pass a ref to the default slot.

When I am using the `h` render function I can just pass a ref:

```
return h('div', {ref: someRef}); // works
```

If I try to do the same with the default slot, it does not work:

```
return slots.default({ ref: someRef}) // does not work
return slots.default({ someRef}) // also does not work
```

Is there any way to do this without wrapping the default slot into another div or similar?

Checked already the documentation and other resources, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: `h('div', {ref: someRef})` assigns a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#ref) to the `div`. When you say "pass ref to default slot", what exactly do you mean? Are you wanting to assign a template ref so that you could later reference the slot components? Or pass a [data `ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) to the slot so that the slot components could use the data?

Comment: A template ref so I can access the html. Passing data and functions works as expected, but not a template ref.

Comment: Can you show an example of this component? A renderless component has no template (hence "renderless"), so how would it have template refs?

Comment: @tony19 Renderless does not mean necessarily no html at all. But usually one wants to pass additional parameters, functions and so on to the default slot (and so a ref). So the component itself does not have own html etc., but can be a wrapper for html which is passed by the parent. 
BTW: My components are inspired by renderless components from Adam Wathan. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Direct answer

Yes return a function from your `setup` hook!

```js
setup(_, slots) { 
  const someRef = ref()

  return () => slots.default({ ref: someRef })
}
```

1. [vue3 docs link](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-render-functions)
2. [vue3 docs for renderless component pattern](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#renderless-components)

#### Contextual answer for those in the comment section questioning the renderless/headless pattern

Yes, sometimes you just want a renderless (or headless as the kids these days say) wrapper for functionality (logic), without limiting the HTML that consumers can use.

But for that functionality to work, the renderless/headless component still needs to identify some of the HTML that consumers render into the default slot, in order to provide DOM-related functionality for example.

I have the same struggle when using this pattern, and have been relying on a "hack": passing specific data attributes via slot scope, that consumers need to bind to the desired elements (not only root) and then using good old `document.querySelector` to grab them

I has served me well in vue2 and I've been using it in production with no problems, but I was wondering if with the new dynamic `:ref` attribute of vue3, we can do it differently: probably passing a reactive `ref` variable and then doing a simple assign, and apparently it works.

```html
<renderless #default="{ someRef }">
   <some-consumer-comp :ref="(el) => someRef.value = el" />
</renderless>
```

1. Here's a [sandbox demo old way for vue 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-click-outside-programatic-usage-o9drq?file=/src/components/RenderlessWithClickOutside.vue)
2. Here's a [sandbox demo new way for vue 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-click-outside-programatic-usage-forked-for-vue3-te6qqk?file=/src/components/RenderlessWithClickOutside.vue)

Do note that if you want to handle edge cases, like handling conditional rendering of slot content, you probably need to do a bit more work and add some watchers.

This pattern is a bit out of fashion these days, with the introduction of vue `composables` since you can abstract the logic into a `useSomeFunctionality` and use it directly on the component you want, but it's sill a valid one IMO.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Actually I already figured this out on my own, but my bad for not answering my own question.